Wi-Fi 6E 802.11ax driver for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I am having ASUS Zephyrus G16 (GU605MI-QP253WS). I want to run ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04. I am not able to access the integrated WiFi Driver in this. My all work deals with this ROS1 version so I have to work in Ubuntu 20.04 (i.e. without using any docker).
My kernel version is 5.15.0-117-generic. (I tried upgrading it but looks like libraries needed to upgrade, requires Ubuntu 22.04 or higher).
Also when i start my laptop there is error like:
 minimum version required: iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-39
 maximum version required: iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-66
Let me know if i need to share more details.
Please help!!
